# Change datasource in javascript based on dropdown click?

Tags: javascript, html, wcf, amcharts

I have an HTML page that looks like this. It includes a dropdown and a `div` used to display a map:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Month<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">11-01-2017</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">12-01-2017</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <div>
        <div id="MapDiv" ></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

`MapDiv` is filled using the following javascript function. It's a WCF that returns a `json` stream. It's hard-coaded to *11-01-2017*:

```
var portsMap = AmCharts.makeChart( "MapDiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "theme": "light",
  "colorSteps": 5,
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "http://OurServer/Service1.svc/GetInfo/11-01-2017"
  ...(OTHER CODE)...
} );
```

My question is: how can I change `dataloader` so that it loads based on my dropdown selection? So if I select *12-01-2017*, then the data displayed will be from date.

Thanks.

Comment: when does AmCharts.makeChart gets called?

Comment: you can use onChange handler on dropdown. pass the date value in your makeChart function.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a listener on the drop down (which you should change to use select tag with options. And on change I would set the url in your map object and then call `.loadData()` on the dataLoader object to update it.

your "dropdown" instead of using `<ul>` should look like

```
<select id="myDropDown" class="dropdown-menu">
  <option value="11-01-2017">11-01-2017</option>
  <option value="12-01-2017">12-01-2017</option>
</select>
```

And the javascript

```
document.getElementById("myDropDown").onchange=setMapURL;

function setMapURL(event) {
  var newDate= event.target.value;
  portsMap.dataLoader.url = "http://OurServer/Service1.svc/GetInfo/" + newDate;
  portsMap.dataLoader.loadData()
}
```

There is also a very good [example](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/dynamically-changing-map-data-sets/) on amcharts website

Comment: This is mostly correct except you have to change the `validateData()` line  to  call `loadData()` from the dataLoader object to reload from the new URL, e.g. `portsMap.dataLoader.loadData()`. `validateData()` doesn't re-trigger the dataLoader.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked, but I had to make some changes. I had to create a function for `document.getElementById("myDropDown").onchange=setMapURL;` and add `OnChange` to the dropdown. With that it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recall api on click on the dropdown, 'AmCharts', what is that ?( I suppose the part of code is call api)

Watch onclick event on the dropdown div element and in the callback function recall portsMap with the new parameters

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can accomplish this by changing your code as outlined below.

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var dataloader = "http://OurServer/Service1.svc/GetInfo/" + $(this).html();

    var portsMap = AmCharts.makeChart( "MapDiv", {
      "type": "map",
      "theme": "light",
      "colorSteps": 5,
      "dataLoader": {
        "url": dataloader
      //...(OTHER CODE)...
    } );

});
```

Comment: You shouldn't call makeChart again to re-draw the map as it consumes extra resources. Andrew's answer is the way to go aside from changing the validateData call to loadData as mentioned in my comment.